How to orchestrate data when Im ingesting with azure data factory (external to fabric) to Lakhouse in fabric
I have an azure data factory, but now the company wants to implement fabric, for some availability in connectors and the existence of the resource.
The plan is to extract data from on premises (sybase, postgres) to the lakehouse in fabric using data factory (external) the issue comes when besides this extraction i need to orchestrate immediately afterwards another process (notebook or another pipeline inside fabric) how could i orchestrate the whole thing... with out dying trying.
Is there maybe any workaround to this issue or recommendations to the problem?

You can use Fabric Data Pipelines like you would use Data Factory, its the mostly the same interface and mostly the same connections

You can do the whole process in a Fabric pipeline, if you have an On Prem Data Gateway (it doesn't support the SHIR).
Otherwise you can start and monitor a Fabric pipeline with the REST API.  So at the end of your external ADF pipeline, kick off a Fabric pipeline to do the downstream work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/pipeline-rest-api#run-on-demand-item-job

Sounds Great, Thank you !
